# PowerShell AD on server or desktop?

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm starting out on creating PowerShell scripts for my company. I'm new the the platform and I plan on creating scripts for AD tasks

If im creating scripts for AD should I be able to run the script on any machine in the domain or does the script have to be run on a machine that is the active directory server?

I don't mind running the script on the server but for testing and creating I would rather run it on my desktop for development and testing

any incite on this?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg413289.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the activedirectory powershell module, then the only requirement is that the machine you're running the script on has this module installed.

This module is a windows feature "Remote Server Administration Tools > Role Administration Tools > AD DS and AD LDS Tool > Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell."

- On a server OS, this can be simply added as a feature through Server Manager
- On a client OS, you will first need to install the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) from Microsoft download centre.  Once that is installed, you then install the feature through "Turn Windows Features on or off"

Additionally, if your script has a dependency on this module, you can also place the following line at the top of your script

```
#Requires -Module activedirectory
```

Then if you try to run this script on a machine without the activedirectory module, it'll produce an error saying the module is missing.  It'll also cause the activedirectory module to be imported if it's not already been imported which is useful on powershell.  Refer to [about_Requires](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847765.aspx) for more information on the #Requires statement

Comment: is there a powershell script to install that :)

Comment: On server OSes, use `Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-Powershell`.  For the client, you need to download the RSAT tools from the Microsoft Download centre i'm afraid.